# Node.js xlsx get number of non-empty rows

Tags: node.js, xlsx, js-xlsx

I use `xlsx` in Node.js application to get the number of total rows. Here is the code

```
const range = xlsx.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref']);
const totalRows = (range.e.r - range.s.r) + 1;
```

The problem is it also counts formatted cells with empty text. I only want to get number of rows with non-empty text. How can I do it using `xlsx` or is there any other library that can count number of rows containing non-empty text?

Answer (score 4):

I know the thread is old but if anyone still looking for an answer, you can use the below code to ignore formatted blank cells:

```
var arr = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(sheet,{blankrows : false, defval: ''});
const totalRows = arr.length+1;
```